# fbs project structure for PySide2 projects

Tags: pyside2, fbs

Working with the excellent fbs tool (great stuff Michael!).

The [manual](https://build-system.fman.io/manual/) has this suggestion about project structure:

> As your application grows in complexity, you will likely want to split
>   its source code across multiple files. In this case, it is recommend
>   that you place them all inside one package.

My tendency is to use subdirectories like 'view','controller','model','service', etc wherein multiple .py files exist. Is there a critical reason one wouldn't want to use subdirectories when using fbs?

Comment: mmm, I think not. These types of questions I recommend asking them as an issue in the official repository.

Comment: I think you may be reading the suggestion far too literally. It would be a severe bug if `fbs` couldn't handle sub-packages.